# Why do I need to change the frequency for accessing a dataframe indexed with DatetimeIndex in Pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I found this example in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176819/referencing-pandas-dataframe-using-a-datetimeindex) from Stackoverflow:

```
import pandas as pd
earliest = pd.Timestamp('2012-01-01 06:00:00')
latest = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-01 23:00:00')
dr = pd.date_range(start=earliest, end=latest,freq="30min")
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(index=dr, columns=['freq'])
df_freq = df_freq.fillna(0)

# use str datetime as key 
df_freq['2012-03-04']
```

That post was published about five years ago, so the pandas API may have changed.
Even when the code still works in 2022, I got this warning:

```
FutureWarning: Indexing a DataFrame with a datetimelike index using a single string
to slice the rows, like `frame[string]`, is deprecated and will be removed in a future 
version. Use `frame.loc[string]` instead.
```

However, it seems that such indexing by datetime only works for specific frequencies.
If you change the frequency from `"30min"` to `"D"` (daily), the same snippet just does not work:

```
import pandas as pd
earliest = pd.Timestamp('2012-01-01')
latest = pd.Timestamp('2014-12-01')
dr = pd.date_range(start=earliest, end=latest, freq="D")     # if freq is D, it does not work
df_freq = pd.DataFrame(index=dr, columns=['freq'])
df_freq = df_freq.fillna(0)

df_freq['2012-03-04']
```

In that case, I got a `KeyError: '2012-03-04'` error message.

The workaround is easy, you must use `df_freq.loc['2012-03-04']` for indexing.
However, I do not know why do I need to change the frequency for accessing a dataframe.
Is this behavior documented elsewhere?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question; are you asking why you can use different indexing methods with different frequencies? The warning recommends `loc`, which works in both cases, no?

Comment: What I tried to say is why `df_freq['2012-03-04']` works when `freq="30min"` but does not work with `df_freq['2012-03-04']`. I know that I must use `df_freq.loc['2012-03-04']` in any case. I just wanted to know if the frequency has a side-effect I was unaware of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The current [`pandas docs`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing) say:

> Warning
>
> Indexing DataFrame rows with a single string with getitem (e.g.
> frame[dtstring]) is deprecated starting with pandas 1.2.0 (given the
> ambiguity whether it is indexing the rows or selecting a column) and
> will be removed in a future version. The equivalent with .loc (e.g.
> frame.loc[dtstring]) is still supported.

When you look at the docs for version [`1.1.5`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.1.5/user_guide/timeseries.html#slice-vs-exact-match) (i.e. last version before `1.2.0`), you'll find that your issue is covered there already:

> Warning
>
> However, if the string is treated as an exact match, the selection in
> DataFrame’s [] will be column-wise and not row-wise, see Indexing
> Basics. For example dft_minute['2011-12-31 23:59'] will raise KeyError
> as '2012-12-31 23:59' has the same resolution as the index and there
> is no column with such name:
>
> To always have unambiguous selection, whether the row is treated as a
> slice or a single selection, use .loc.

So, returning to your specific situation, in your first example with `freq="30min"`, `df_freq['2012-03-04']` is *not* an exact match. E.g.:

```
print(df_freq['2012-03-04'].head())

                     freq
2012-03-04 00:00:00     0
2012-03-04 00:30:00     0
2012-03-04 01:00:00     0
2012-03-04 01:30:00     0
2012-03-04 02:00:00     0
```

However, in your second example with `freq="D"`, `df_freq['2012-03-04']` *does* constitute an exact match. As a result, the program starts looking for a `column` match, rather than an `index` match. And since your `df_freq` does not have any such column, you receive the error. Indeed, the last part of the traceback for `df_freq['2012-03-04']` applied to your second example shows you this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "script.py", line 8, in <module>
    df_freq['2012-03-04']

  File "..\pandas\core\frame.py", line 3505, in __getitem__
    indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)

  File "..\pandas\core\indexes\base.py", line 3623, in get_loc
    raise KeyError(key) from err

KeyError: '2012-03-04'
```

Note `indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)`. I.e. the failure lies with `df_freq.columns.get_loc('2012-03-04')`.

So, the problem doesn't have anything to do with the selected frequency, really. Something like `df_freq['2012-03']` for your second example would still get you a slice as well (but with the same warning, of course).

The problem is also avoidable by using `df_freq['2012-03-04':'2012-03-04']`. Applied to your second example:

```
print(df_freq['2012-03-04':'2012-03-04'])

            freq
2012-03-04     0
```

However, note that this returns a `df`-slice:

```
print(type(df_freq['2012-03-04':'2012-03-04']))
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
```

Contrast `.loc`:

```
print(type(df_freq.loc['2012-03-04']))
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```